# How to fix "Unable to verify the first certificate" when testing axios-based API with JEST and axios-mock-adapter?

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs, axios, axios-mock-adapter

I'm using `Jest` and `axios-mock-adapter` to write tests for my API services.  The problem is that when I run the test I get an error stating:

> Error: unable to verify the first certificate.

`app.service.js` is the following

```
import ApiService from '@/services/api.service'

export default {
  async loadDashboard (psRef) {
    let result = await ApiService.get('user/' + psRef + '/dashboard')
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
      })
    return result.data
  }
}
```

`api.service.js` is where I create my `axios` instance like so

```
import Axios from 'axios'

const baseDomain = process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND
const baseURL = `${baseDomain}${process.env.VUE_APP_API}`

export default Axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

The test is the following:

```
const baseDomain = process.env.VUE_APP_BACKEND
const baseURL = `${baseDomain}${process.env.VUE_APP_API}`

test('loadDashboard should return the dashboard data for the user', async () => {
  mock.onGet(`${baseURL}user/85/dashboard`).reply(200, { dashBoardData })

  let response = await AppService.loadDashboard(85)
  expect(response).toEqual(dashBoardData)

  // AppService.loadDashboard(85).then(response => {
  //   expect(response.data).toEqual(dashBoardData)
  // })
})
```

Does anybody know how to fix this error?

Comment: Perhaps related? I am also getting this error with axios while running tests, but _am not_ using `axios-mock-adapter` 

I've added the cert to my trusted root store in windows and all passes when running the application. It's only while testing that I receive this error. Sorry to hijack your issue if it's unrelated :)

Comment: @phillyslick Well then it's not about what mock we are using but something else. I'm still getting the error but have parked it for now since I could not find a solution.